# How to get run-time arguments programatically in grails

Tags: grails, configuration

I'm developing a sample grails application which runs in different environment. I will pass the environment name as runtime argument like below,

```
grail run-app –Denv=dev1
grail run-app –Denv=dev2
```

I need to get the environment name `dev1` or `dev2` programatically. I'll be using the values in GSPs. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grails.util.Environment` :

```
println Environment.currentEnvironment.name
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this in my case. The above statement gives me 'development'. i'm expecting 'dev1'.

Comment: Try `-Dgrails.env` behind the command `grails -Dgrails.env=dev1 run-app`